# how to get django forms.Form dynamic form in python based on other form user mark

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

how to create dynamic form choice based in other form choice in django ?
in python 2.7 django 1.11,  i want to make forms.ChoiceField dynamic in thr python code based on other choice field choosing of the user . my code is :

```
   def get_mgmnt_form():
        from django import forms
        mode_list = ['first_mode', 'second_mode']
        modes = sorted(zip(mode_list, mode_list), key=lambda x: x[0])

        class CustomForm(forms.Form):
            mode = forms.ChoiceField(modes, required=True, label='Runnning Mode', )
            mail = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email', min_length=9)
            categories_names = ['category_1','category_2','category_3']
            categories = zip(categories_names, categories_names)
            category_names = forms.ChoiceField(categories, required=True, label='Categorys', )
            category_field = forms.ChoiceField('dynamic field from DB based on selected category_names', required=True, label='dynamic field of chosen Category', )


        return CustomForm
```

Comment: You could use javascript for that. Or you could override the ```__init__``` method and change the choices based on the category_names field.

Comment: can you please add an example ? i am not sure i understand how to do so

Comment: Something like this. But you will need to submit the form on change of the category_names.
`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if self.data['category_names']:
          self.fields['category_field'].choices = [(t.id, t.title) for t in DynamicTable.objects.filter(name=self.data['category_names'])]`

Comment: i have tried but in the init the category_names is not chosen and not defined yet , in the init self.data is empty

Comment: I don't want to submit the form, just something like hida and show in js based on other form